# Use Multiple for loop to get combinations of all elements

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, combinations

I'm trying to use combination for multiple elements in three character vector, but I 'm getting only last element iterations, **also I want to put a condition that my *budg_min* should not be greater than *budg_max* while creating a list of combinations**

here is my code

```
    text1="http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom="
    text3="&proptype="
    text4="Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment"
    text5="&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin="
    text6="&BudgetMax="


    uuu=list()
    bhk=c("1","2","3","4","5",">5")
    budg_min=c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")
    budg_max=c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")

    for(i in bhk){
      for(j in budg_min){
        for(k in budg_max) {
      if(budg_min>budg_max){"Skip that combination "}
else{


     uuu[i]=paste(text1,i,text3,text4,text5,j,text6,k,sep = "")
         }
     }
    }
    }
```

I'm expecting output like

```
[1]
http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMax=5-Lacs
[2]
http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs
[3]
http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=20-Lacs
.
.
.
.
[n]
http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=%3E5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMax=20-Crores
```

> **note**:in the output above 1st element of list contains only **BudgetMax**
>   parameter AND last(nth) element of list has only **BudgetMax** parameter
>   and rest elements are the combination of  bhk , budg_min and budg_min.

But what my code gives is just 6 records

```
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"

$`2`
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"

$`3`
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=3&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"

$`4`
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=4&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"

$`5`
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"

$`>5`
[1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=>5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=20-Crores&BudgetMax=20-Crores"
```

What changes should be made to my code so that it gives my all combinations.
Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use for-loops. With `expand.grid` and `sprintf`:

```
eg <- expand.grid(bhk = bhk, budg_min = budg_min, budg_max = budg_max)
eg <- eg[as.integer(eg$budg_min) <= as.integer(eg$budg_max),]
uuu <- sprintf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", text1,eg[,1],text3,text4,text5,eg[,2],text6,eg[,3])
```

you get the desired result as well:

> ```
> > head(uuu,10)
>  [1] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [2] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [3] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=3&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [4] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=4&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [5] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [6] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=>5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=5-Lacs"
>  [7] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs"
>  [8] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=2&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs"
>  [9] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=3&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs"
> [10] "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=4&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs"
> ```

Explanation:

- With `expand.grid` you create all combinations of the vectors `bhk`, `budg_min` and `budg_max`.
- Because the levels of the factor variables `budg_min` and `budg_max` are in increasing order of the currency values, you can filter out the cases where `budg_min > budg_max` by converting these factors to integer.
- `sprintf` pastes all the vectors together according to the specified format (`"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s"`). Each `%s` part of the format is replaced by the elements of the vectors.

---

To convert all the currency values to *lacs*, you could do (inspired by @MattJewett):

```
eg <- expand.grid(bhk = bhk, budg_min = budg_min, budg_max = budg_max) 

# Convert values to lacs prior to min/max comparison
eg$min_lacs <- as.numeric(gsub('([0-9.]+).*','\\1',eg$budg_min))
eg$min_lacs[grepl('Crores',eg$budg_min)] <- eg$min_lacs[grepl('Crores',eg$budg_min)]*100
eg$max_lacs <- as.numeric(gsub('([0-9.]+).*','\\1',eg$budg_min))
eg$max_lacs[grepl('Crores',eg$budg_max)] <- eg$max_lacs[grepl('Crores',eg$budg_max)]*100

eg <- eg[as.integer(eg$min_lacs) <= as.integer(eg$max_lacs),]
uuu <- sprintf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", text1,eg[,1],text3,text4,text5,eg[,2],text6,eg[,3])
```

Comment: your code works fine but kindly see the post again ,Since I have edited it with some thing as well...Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Yeah this worked.. This is the savior for the day..Thanks a ton for the effort!!!

Comment: @deepesh I've included a conversion now as well

Comment: yes... saw the update,, this is so nice to have all in one .... Thanks once again!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `apply`, you can scratch the loop.

`expand.grid` gives you all combinations of your three vectors:

```
allcombs <-expand.grid(bhk = bhk,bmin = budg_min, bmax =budg_max)
```

You create an index where `budg_min`is smaller or equal to `budg_max`:

```
ix <- apply(allcombs,1,function(x) which(budg_min %in% x[2]) <= which(budg_max %in% x[3]))
```

And then form only the combinations which are true given your condition:

```
res <- apply(allcombs[ix,],1,function(x) paste(text1,x[1],text3,text4,text5,x[2],text6,x[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks much for the effort. your script works absolutely fine, but I have edited the post with some other condition as well. Thanks for the effort!!!

Comment: Absolutely @Val this worked very well with the condition ...Thank you soo much for the effort!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value at uuu[i] every time a new k element is created.

For instance the first run through the loop
i == 1, j == 1, k == 1
You then assign your first value to uuu[1]
The second run through
i == 1, j == 1, k == 2
You then also assign your second value to uuu[1] (because i still equals 1)

To fix this you need a separate counter to keep track of the items in your list.

Something like this should give you every combination in a new element.

```
text1 <- "http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom="
text3 <- "&proptype="
text4 <- "Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment"
text5 <- "&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin="
text6 <-"&BudgetMax="


uuu <- list()
bhk <- c("1","2","3","4","5",">5")
budg_min <- c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")
budg_max <- c("5-Lacs","10-Lacs","20-Lacs","30-Lacs","40-Lacs","50-Lacs","60-Lacs","70-Lacs","80-Lacs","90-Lacs","1-Crores","1.2-Crores","1.4-Crores","1.6-Crores","1.8-Crores","2-Crores","2.3-Crores","2.6-Crores","3-Crores","3.5-Crores","4-Crores","4.5-Crores","5-Crores","10-Crores","20-Crores")
item <- 1

for(i in bhk){
  for(j in budg_min){
    # Split budg_min to separate value from unit
    min <- unlist(strsplit(j,"-"))
    # Convert Crores to Lacs to get min value in Lacs
    min <- ifelse(min[2] == "Crores", as.numeric(min[1]) * 100, as.numeric(min[1]))

    for(k in budg_max) {
      # Split budg_min to separate value from unit
      max <- unlist(strsplit(k,"-"))
      # Convert Crores to Lacs to get max value in Lacx
      max <- ifelse(max[2] == "Crores", as.numeric(max[1]) * 100, as.numeric(max[1]))

      # If min is less than max, insert the comparison
      if(min < max){
        uuu[item] <- paste(text1,i,text3,text4,text5,j,text6,k,sep = "")
        item <- item + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Matt Jeweett. I have edited the post with some other condition as well. kindly go through it again.. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I've updated my solution to handle the min/max comparison. It also has some code in there that can be used to handle the conversion of crores to lacs, which should give a more accurate comparison of the values. You may want to find a way to incorporate that into the solution provided by @Jaap to ensure the values are compared as the same monetary unit.

Comment: Thx for the suggested edit. Hope you don't mind I've rejected it, because imo it could be done more efficently. See the update of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that uuu[i] is what's causing the problems. Try this:

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in bhk){
  for(j in budg_min){
    for(k in budg_max) {
      uuu=data.frame(paste(text1,i,text3,text4,text5,j,text6,k,sep = ""))
      df <- rbind(df, uuu)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the combination created in "df"  contain some url which doesn't exist.so edited my post with other condition as well.....For e.g if you go through the dataframe "df" in row number "26,51,52,76,77,78" contains the link where   budg_min becomes greater than budg_max, which ideally is not the case. so for this kind of url's it doesn't give any records. So any suggestion on the same. Thanks for the effort!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider even sapply/vapply with multiple args:

```
mat <- sapply(budg_min, function(j, k, i, t1, t3, t4, t5, t6) 
  paste0(t1,i,t3,t4,t5,j,t6,k), budg_max, bhk, text1, text3, text4, text5, text6)

mat <- vapply(budg_min, function(j, k, i, t1, t3, t4, t5, t6) 
  paste0(t1,i,t3,t4,t5,j,t6,k), character(25), USE.NAMES = TRUE, budg_max, bhk, text1, text3, text4, text5, text6)
```

The return of either above is a named column matrix (names from first input list or *budg_min*). But should you want long character vector use `as.vector(mat)`

[image]